# Questions about Jensen inequality and integrability

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space and $X: \Omega \to (a,b)$ a $P$-integrable random variable and $\phi: (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ a convex function.

Then, the expectation of $\phi \circ X$ exists and $$\phi(\mathbb EX)\leq \mathbb E(\phi \circ X)$$

> What does 'the expectation of $\phi \circ X$ exists' mean?

a) Does this mean it is finite?

**Or:**

Does it mean the following: We call a measurable function $f$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu)$ integrable with respect to $\mu$ if $\max\{\int f^+ d\mu, \int f^- d\mu\}< \infty$ where $f^+=\max (f,0)$ and $f^- = \max(-f,0)$.

b) So the expecation of $X$ exists when $X$ is integrable with respect to $P$ in this context?

c) or: are these the same?

One more question:
In the proof there is the following line:

$$\phi(X(\omega))\geq \phi(\mathbb EX)+\partial^r\phi(\mathbb EX)(X(\omega)-\mathbb EX)$$

$\partial^r \phi(x)$ denotes $\lim_{y \searrow x} \frac{\phi(y)-\phi(x)}{y-x}$

Then the author states that the integral of $\phi \circ X$ exists with respect to $P$ because the right hand side of the above inequality is integrable. I understand why the right hand side is integrable. But I don't understand why this implies that the integral of the left hand side exists, because we have $LHS \geq RHS$ instead of $LHS \leq RHS$

Comment: The correct interpretation is b). The inequality from the proof then ensures that $\int (\phi \circ f)_{-} dP <\infty$. It can happen that $\int \phi \circ f dP =\infty$.